# class System.Uri C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Tengo un proyecto de librerias (dll) donde tengo el siguiente fragmento de código, y tengo un  public FreshdeskService y tiene definidos 2 parámetros (string apiKey, Uri apiUri)

```
 public FreshdeskService(string apiKey, Uri apiUri) {
        ApiKey = apiKey;
        ApiUri = apiUri;
        // Force TLS 1.1 or higher. Anything lower is deprecated in the Freshdesk API as of 2016-09-30
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        foreach (SecurityProtocolType p in SecurityProtocolType.GetValues(typeof(SecurityProtocolType))) {
            if (p > SecurityProtocolType.Tls11) ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= p;
        }
    }
```

y en otro proyecto de consola agregue la referencia del proyecto de librerías a mi proyecto ejecutable, y quiero mandarle los parámetros correspondientes, solo que no se como mandarle el parametro al Uri apiUri, tengo el siguiente codigo que me muestra error

```
FreshdeskService freshdesk = new FreshdeskService("YJO0scpcd7NLoGKDtZ", "https://bozhelp.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets");
```

quisiera saber la forma correcta de mandarle el parámetro correspondiente al Uri, para que haya comunicacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que instanciar la clase `Uri` usando:

```
Uri ticketUri = new Uri("https://bozhelp.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets");

FreshdeskService freshdesk = new FreshdeskService("YJO0scpcd7NLoGKDtZ", ticketUri);
```

pasas por parametro el string de la url

[Uri Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.5)

Comment: muchas gracias, resolvió mi problema sin problema!!